# wordpress add filter not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to replace the admin dashboard function that displays the 'Right Now' panel. I have my own function displaying other info but it's simply not picking up.

```
add_filter('wp_dashboard_right_now', 'wp_dashboard_my_summary', 1, 0);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Given [WP Plugin API Filter Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference), there is no such filter **wp_dashboard_right_now** .

There are a few actions that you can use tough ( carefull they are not fiters but actions ) :

- right_now_content_table_end
- right_now_table_end
- right_now_discussion_table_end
- rightnow_end
- activity_box_end